# With redirect code should I use for geoip language redirect?

Tags: protocols, seo

I have this URL: http://example.com/website/ then I check user country based on geoip and redirect them to: http://example.com/website/en/, http://example.com/website/pt/ etc..

Witch code should I use for this redirect 301, 302 or other?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to go with **307 Temporary Redirect**:

> The requested resource resides
>   temporarily under a different URI.
>   Since the redirection MAY be altered
>   on occasion, the client SHOULD
>   continue to use the Request-URI for
>   future requests.

That way you won't run into snags with search engines purging the page.

Comment: Also ensure that the Cache-Control and/or Expires headers specify an appropriate caching period.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [303 See Other](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4).